# Access auto-generated abp template

Tags: angular, abp

I'm working with ABP framework, using Angular for the UI, I replaced a component using this [abp tutorial](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Component-Replacement)

It works; I get the value of my custom component showing in the personal settings.

```
this.replaceableComponents.add({
    component: CustomPersonalSettingsComponent,
    key: eAccountComponents.PersonalSettings
  })
```

But the only customization I want is to add a new field; I want the auto-generated html code back and the ts component too. I looked in the abp git to see if I can found them, but I couldn't. Is there a way to access personal settings component files?

Comment: Hi, could you please review the relevant [question](https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/1404/Customizing-PersonalSettings-Personal-Info-page-not-working#answer-9791e83b-44ef-a138-e812-39fcd3713128)?

Comment: I did, but the question is outdated for the current framework version it does not work @onurpicakci